# How to chain order, group, mutate, pivot in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to **data.table** & trying to replicate some **dplyr** code but having issues with **pivot / reshaping data** in data.table code.

**libs**

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
```

**df**

```
test_df <- data.frame(id = c(1234, 1234, 5678, 5678),
           date = c("2021-10-10","2021-10-10", "2021-8-10", "2021-8-15"),
           Amount  = c(54767, 96896, 34534, 79870)) %>% 
  
  mutate(date = ymd(date))
```

**dplyr code:**

```
test_df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Amt_first = first(Amount),
         Amt_last = last(Amount)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  pivot_longer(cols = c(Amt_first:Amt_last), names_to = "Amt_catg", 
  values_to = "Amt_val")
```

results:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
     id date       Amount Amt_catg  Amt_val
  <dbl> <date>      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1  5678 2021-08-10  34534 Amt_first   34534
2  5678 2021-08-10  34534 Amt_last    79870
3  5678 2021-08-15  79870 Amt_first   34534
4  5678 2021-08-15  79870 Amt_last    79870
5  1234 2021-10-10  54767 Amt_first   54767
6  1234 2021-10-10  54767 Amt_last    96896
7  1234 2021-10-10  96896 Amt_first   54767
8  1234 2021-10-10  96896 Amt_last    96896
```

**data.table attempt**:

```
setDT(test_df)[order(date),
             `:=`(Amt_first = data.table::first(Amount),
                   Amt_last = data.table::last(Amount)), 
             by = id] %>% 
    
    # https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html
  data.table::melt(measure.vars = c("Amt_first","Amt_Last"),
                   variable.name = "Amt_catg", value.name = "Amt_val")
```

I am getting an error here.

Comment: *"I am getting an error here"*. **Please** don't keep secrets from us. If you are getting an error, include it in the question, especially when the premise of the question is based on that one error. In this case Waldi found it, maybe without having to run the code. In this case, I suspect that if we immediately saw `One or more values in 'measure.vars' is invalid`, somebody would have checked your `measure.vars = c("Amt_first","Amt_Last")` to do a quick comparison with previous code/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error because you misspelled `Amt_last` :

```
setDT(test_df)[order(date),
                 `:=`(Amt_first = data.table::first(Amount),
                      Amt_last = data.table::last(Amount)), 
                 by = id] %>%
  data.table::melt(id.vars=c('id','date'),measure.vars = c("Amt_first","Amt_last"),
                   variable.name = "Amt_catg", value.name = "Amt_val")

     id       date Amount  Amt_catg Amt_val
1: 1234 2021-10-10  54767 Amt_first   54767
2: 1234 2021-10-10  96896 Amt_first   54767
3: 5678 2021-08-10  34534 Amt_first   34534
4: 5678 2021-08-15  79870 Amt_first   34534
5: 1234 2021-10-10  54767  Amt_last   96896
6: 1234 2021-10-10  96896  Amt_last   96896
7: 5678 2021-08-10  34534  Amt_last   79870
8: 5678 2021-08-15  79870  Amt_last   79870
```

Answer (score 1):

The output can be achieved with a full join:

```
setDT(test_df)

merge(
  test_df,
  test_df[order(date), 
          .(Amt_catg = c('Amt_first', 'Amt_last'), 
            Amt_val = Amount[c(1L, .N)]), 
          by = id]
)

#      id       date Amount  Amt_catg Amt_val
# 1: 1234 2021-10-10  54767 Amt_first   54767
# 2: 1234 2021-10-10  54767  Amt_last   96896
# 3: 1234 2021-10-10  96896 Amt_first   54767
# 4: 1234 2021-10-10  96896  Amt_last   96896
# 5: 5678 2021-08-10  34534 Amt_first   34534
# 6: 5678 2021-08-10  34534  Amt_last   79870
# 7: 5678 2021-08-15  79870 Amt_first   34534
# 8: 5678 2021-08-15  79870  Amt_last   79870
```